# Saving an array and reading it again

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file, save, savefiledialog

I have an array generated with random values. When I am saving the array, the txt file generated is just filled with System.String[,] instead of the values I am trying to save. How do i fix this?

```
Dim strFileName As String = String.Empty
    'Set the Save dialog properties
    With SaveFileDialog1
        .DefaultExt = "txt"
        .Filter = "Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .OverwritePrompt = True
        .Title = "Save File"
    End With
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> String.Empty Then
        Try
            'Save the file path and name
            strFileName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName

            SaveFile(strFileName, valuein)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title,
              MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
Sub SaveFile(ByVal path As String, ByVal textToSave As String)

    Dim strmWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path, False) 'false = don't append to an existing file
    For Each i In Value
        strmWriter.Write(Value)
    Next
    'strmWriter.Write(textToSave)

    strmWriter.Close()
    strmWriter.Dispose()
    'Show the file using the default text file viewer ( probably Notepad will show ).>>
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each i In Value strmWriter.Write(i) Next`

Comment: If you have a `String` array, just save it by calling `File.WriteAllLines`. You can then load with a call to `File.ReadAllLines`. One line of code in each direction.

Comment: omg im an idiot. thank you!